# Highcharts.js, how to zoom in on one chart to resize another as Stackoverflow has done?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'd like to replicate how StackOverflow has built their [reputation column charts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702275/tim-peterson?tab=reputation).

Specifically, I'm interested in the behavior of zooming in on the bottom chart to resize the top chart. I'm wondering if there is an option in Highcharts.js for this or whether this was a homemade extension made by SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks a lot like this demo, except that this is a line chart and not a column chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

Also available for testing on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-master-detail/

Here's a jsfiddle of Stackoverflow's actual code which is minimized but you get the idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/abex2/1/