# Making a master-detail Highchart in Stackoverflow style

Tags: highcharts

I came across the Highcharts demo gallery, where the master detail chart at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail/gray) looks very similar to the reputation graph for users provided in Stackoverflow. There is one difference, the one in Stackoverflow shows the detailed graph in the form of vertical bars, whereas the one in the Highcharts demo gallery is in the form of a continuous graph. Is there any option through which the detailed map can be changed to vertical bar type?

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228847/highcharts-js-how-to-zoom-in-on-one-chart-to-resize-another-as-stackoverflow-ha/11229976#11229976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible. I would recommend using HighStock instead as its the chart that has better functionality for timeseries kind of data.

Here is how you do it in highstock, just set the series type of navigator to 'column'

```
  navigator: {
        series: {
            data: ADBE,
            type : 'column'
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLqL3/1/
PS: I have changed only one of the line graphs (lower) to column and left the other one as exercise ;)

All the said the same can very much be done in highcharts too, the master detail chart there is a combination of more than one chart, the master being the same as the navigator in highstock, and detail is the main chart, so you can as well set the series type of the master to be 'column' there and you are done, fiddled @ http://jsfiddle.net/RAXa3/1/

```
    series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
                data: data
            }],
```

You could have explored the reputation chart scripts to dig out your solution

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: "master-graph",
    animation: !1,
    reflow: !1,
    borderWidth: 0,
    marginLeft: 62,
    backgroundColor: null,
    zoomType: "x",
    events: {
        selection: function(a){
            varb=a.xAxis[
                0
            ],
            a=b.min,
            b=b.max,
            c=this.xAxis[
                0
            ];c.removePlotBand("selected-area");c.addPlotBand({
                id: "selected-area",
                from: a,
                to: b,
                color: "rgba(0, 70, 200, 0.2)"
            });e(this);return!1
        }
    }
},
series: [
    {
        data: i,
        type: "column",
        color: "green"
    }
],
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: !1,
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            enabled: !1
        },
        shadow: !1,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        enableMouseTracking: !1
    },
    column: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    }
},
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    min: a,
    max: p,
    maxZoom: 2592E6,
    plotBands: [
        {
            id: "selected-area",
            from: h,
            to: p,
            color: "rgba(0, 70, 200, 0.2)"
        }
    ],
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function(){
            returnHighcharts.dateFormat(7776E6<p-a?"%b '%y": "%b %e",
            this.value,
            !1)
        }
    },
    lineWidth: 0
},
yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        enabled: !1
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    plotLines: b(),
    min: j,
    max: m,
    showFirstLabel: !1,
    endOnTick: !1,
    startOnTick: !1
},
title: {
    text: null
},
legend: {
    enabled: !1
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function(){
        return!1
    }
},
credits: {
    enabled: !1
},
exporting: {
    enabled: !1
}
});
```

AND

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: "detail-graph",
    animation: !1,
    defaultSeriesType: "column"
},
series: [
    {
        name: "rep",
        data: g,
        color: "green"
    }
],
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: !1,
        cursor: "pointer",
        allowPointSelect: !0,
        shadow: !1,
        stickyTracking: !0,
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: !0,
                brightness: 0.5
            }
        }
    },
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.03,
        groupPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        events: {
            click: c
        }
    }
},
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    labels: {
        rotation: 0,
        formatter: function(){
            returnHighcharts.dateFormat("%b %e",
            this.value,
            !1)
        }
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: f,
    max: d,
    startOnTick: !0,
    endOnTick: !0
},
yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    plotLines: b(),
    min: e,
    max: h,
    title: {
        text: "reputation per day"
    },
    startOnTick: !1,
    endOnTick: !1
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function(){
        return'<spanstyle="font-size: 10px;">'+Highcharts.dateFormat("%A, %B %e, %Y",
        this.point.x,
        !1)+'</span><br/><spanstyle="color:'+this.series.color+'">'+this.series.name+"</span>: <b>"+this.point.realRep+"</b>"
    },
    style: {
        lineHeight: "200%",
        padding: 10
    }
},
title: {
    text: null
},
legend: {
    enabled: !1
},
credits: {
    enabled: !1
}
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was one heck of an answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, ummm, your Highstock demo in jsFiddle still shows continuous graph in the main graph.

Comment: Same goes for you Highcharts demo in Fiddle!

Comment: Ya, the default one has the navigator as continuous too :) so i thought I ll change one of the graphs and leave the other one as exercise ;)

Comment: Ummm, shouldn't you give one example and leave one for exercise? Looks like you have left both for exercise.

Comment: Ohh, I wasn't clear i think. Each of the charts, the highchart and highstock fiddle examples, has two charts in themselves, one the master and other the detail, both being line charts by default, i made the master (navigator) to a column and left the detail as exercise, hence I said that I did one (the master) and left the other (detail) as an exercise

Comment: That doesn't address the issue. I don't want the master chart to be in the form of columns, I wanted the chart above to be in the form of columns, just like in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Updaed the links in the answer for you, http://jsfiddle.net/RAXa3/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/bLqL3/1/